# MySQL query timing out

Tags: mysql, timeout

I am having trouble with the SQL query below...it pegs the CPU on my server and eventually times out without returning the result. Does the format of the query look ok?

BD

```
SELECT dfa_data_dump.date,
       campaignname,
       placementgroup,
       placementstartdate,
       placementenddate,
       placementgrouptotalbookedunits,
       placementgroupid,
       sitename,
       dfa_data_dump.placementid,
       placement,
       dfa_data_dump.placementrate,
       placement_rates.ratetype,
       placementtotalbookedunits,
       placementsize,
       time_dimension.month,
       Sum(impressionsdelivered),
       Sum(clicksrecorded),
       Sum(totalactivities),
       Sum(totalcost)
FROM   dfa_data_dump
       INNER JOIN time_dimension
               ON time_dimension.date = dfa_data_dump.date
       INNER JOIN placement_rates
               ON placement_rates.placementid = dfa_data_dump.placementid
GROUP  BY dfa_data_dump.date,
          campaignname,
          placementgroup,
          placementgrouptotalbookedunits,
          placementgroupid,
          sitename,
          placementid,
          placement,
          placementrate,
          placementtotalbookedunits,
          placementsize,
          time_dimension.month
```

Comment: You need to provide way more info. What does your table structure look like? Indexes? Can you provide a DESCRIBE result? It's probably the grouping and aggregation that takes time.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that your query is originated in a CGI, and that times out and then kills the mysql query. Direct database from CGI means that your queries MUST be quick, or you run into this trouble.

So you either need to make it faster, or you put the fetching into a back end script that is not time critical.

You can probably increase the performance dramatically using indexes - index the columns that you are joining on for a start. That may be enough to fix it, the next one is to look at your GROUP BY columns - there are quite a few  of them, and it's this that may be hurting you. It depends a little on how much data there is that you are making it group by, and how many different values appear there.